# Pinescript, getting number of shares outstanding

Tags: pine-script

Hey I am testing out pinescript of tradingview.

How can I get the number of shares outstanding for the stock using pinescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new function is now available to access financials from Pine:

https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/built-in-financial-functions-and-metrics-in-pine-17491/

Answer (score 1):

Financials appear on your chart as an indicator. You can use the values from one of those at a time in a script by hooking it up via an external output.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer,
However, I am looking for a way to add this to my pine-script.

I tried ESDFACTS but can't find the api to look for the right syntax

Comment: Other than using the external output method we linked to, there is no way to access this data from a script, afawk. A feature to allow it is being planned, however.

Answer (score 0):

[Supposedly](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000564727-what-financial-data-is-available-in-pine/) you can do something like this (I am getting 0 for `FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING`):

```
val = nz(request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FY", ignore_invalid_symbol = true))
```

But it works for `TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING`